# ColorScheme Not Working-Just Blue Color (Spacevim)

Tags: spacevim

Today when i opened spacevim the ColorScheme was just blue! [image: blue theme]

My init.toml:

```
[options]
# set spacevim theme. by default colorscheme layer is not loaded,
# if you want to use more colorscheme, please load the colorscheme
# layer
colorscheme = "onedark"
colorscheme_bg = "dark"
# Disable guicolors in basic mode, many terminal do not support 24bit
# true colors
enable_guicolors = true
# Disable statusline separator, if you want to use other value, please
# install nerd fonts
statusline_separator = "arrow"
statusline_inactive_separator = "arrow"
buffer_index_type = 4
enable_tabline_filetype_icon = true

enable_statusline_mode = false
[[layers]]
name = 'autocomplete'
auto-completion-return-key-behavior = "complete"
auto-completion-tab-key-behavior = "smart"

[[layers]]
name="colorscheme"

[[layers]]
name = 'shell'
default_position = 'top'
default_height = 30

[[layers]]
name="lang#python"
```

Vim Version:

```
    VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr 23 2019 20:00:52)
    macOS version
    Included patches: 1-1200
    Compiled by Homebrew
    Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
    +acl               +extra_search      +mouse_netterm     -tag_old_static
    +arabic            -farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
    +autocmd           +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
    +autochdir         +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
    -autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
    -balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
    +balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
    -browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
    ++builtin_terms    +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +textprop
    +byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +timers
    +channel           +iconv             +packages          +title
    +cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        -toolbar
    -clientserver      +job               +perl              +user_commands
    +clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +vartabs
    +cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vertsplit
    +cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +virtualedit
    +cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +visual
    +comments          +libcall           -python            +visualextra
    +conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +viminfo
    +cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +vreplace
    +cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +wildignore
    +cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildmenu
    +cursorshape       +lua               +ruby              +windows
    +dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        +writebackup
    +diff              +mksession         +signs             -X11
    +digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -xfontset
    -dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       -xim
    -ebcdic            -mouseshape        +statusline        -xpm
    +emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xsmp
    +eval              -mouse_gpm         +syntax            -xterm_clipboard
    +ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        -xterm_save
       system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
         user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
     2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
          user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
           defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
      fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
    Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X -DMACOS_X_DARWIN  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
    Linking: clang   -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lncurses -liconv -lintl -framework AppKit  -L/usr/local/opt/lua/lib -llua5.3 -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -lutil -lc  -L/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-darwin -lpython3.7m -framework CoreFoundation  -lruby.2.6
```

Comment: is this spacevim? how about you ask on there issue tracker? Those are not vi(m) configuration settings.

Comment: Turn off guicolors.

Comment: How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just back to normal when I update iTerm2. It should be an 'true color' issue with iTerm2 according to [github comminity](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/issues/2824#issuecomment-492023825)